# Chart Axis Labels Interval Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, axis-labels

I'm making a chart that will show attendance over a variable amount of time selected from a `dropdown` list. I'm trying to change the intervals of the x axis based on the selected value. I used code from MSDN's chart controls tutorial, but the problem is that when I select the dropdown items, I only get one or two intervals.

When I select 1 (1 month), I get one interval starting at 10/14, the minimum date.
When I select 3 (3 months), I should get several two-week intervals, but instead I only get 2 month-long intervals.

Can someone help me figure out why I'm getting those results and how I can fix it?

The code below shows what I have so far in the event handler for the dropdown list:

```
public void AttendanceChange(Object sender, EventArgs e){
        string StatusSelect = this.AttendanceSelect.SelectedValue;
    int Time = Convert.ToInt32(StatusSelect);

    if (Time == 1)
        SetAxisInterval(Chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX, 1, DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks);
    else if (Time == 3)
        SetAxisInterval(Chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX, 1, DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks);
    else if (Time == 6)
        SetAxisInterval(Chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX, 1, DateTimeIntervalType.Months);
    else if (Time == 12)
        SetAxisInterval(Chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX, 2, DateTimeIntervalType.Months);
    else if (Time == 24)
        SetAxisInterval(Chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX, 3, DateTimeIntervalType.Months);
}
```

Here is the method to change the intervals:

```
public void SetAxisInterval(Axis axis, int interval, DateTimeIntervalType intervalType)
{
    axis.Interval = interval;
    axis.IntervalType = intervalType;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks, John! I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here has to do with the fact that each date being loaded in is counted as a day of the week instead of as a week in itself. I'm looking for an answer to that question in this post: [.Net Chart displaying dates as days in a week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614209/net-chart-displaying-dates-as-days-in-a-week).