# .Net Chart displaying dates as days in a week

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, charts

I'm making a chart in C# that is linked to donation data. Each week, the total donations are recorded in the table. The chart pulls those numbers and graphs them in a line graph.

The problem that I'm having is that each week is being recorded as a day of the week, and so controls that should work based on weeks are not working correctly. I attached my code and a picture of the result below.

I want to know why each data point here is being displayed as a day of the week. Is it how I'm loading the data?

Thanks for any help that you can give.

Here's my code:

```
        #region Chart4
        string DonationSelect = this.DonationSelect.SelectedValue;
        Time = Convert.ToInt32(DonationSelect);

        if (Time > 3)
            Chart4.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
        else
            Chart4.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

        Chart4.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        Chart4.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;

        StartDate = GetNextDay(DateTime.Today, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        TargetDate = GetNextDay(StartDate.AddMonths(-1 * Time), DayOfWeek.Sunday);

        for (DateTime i = TargetDate; i <= DateTime.Now; i = i.AddDays(7))
        {
            int Donations = 0;
            var oDonation = oDatabase.ExecuteScalar(@"SELECT Offering FROM 
            tblStats WHERE Date=@Date",
                "Date", i);

            if (oDonation != null && oDonation != DBNull.Value)
            {
                Donations = Convert.ToInt32(oDonation);
            }
            //int Attendance = Convert.ToInt32();

            string Date = i.ToShortDateString();

            Chart4.Series[0].Points.AddXY(Date, Donations);
        }

        StripLine StripLine = new StripLine();

        StripLine.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        StripLine.Interval = 1;
        StripLine.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks;
        StripLine.StripWidth = .5;
        StripLine.StripWidthType = DateTimeIntervalType.Weeks;
        StripLine.IntervalOffset = 0;
        StripLine.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;

        Chart4.Legends.Add(new Legend("Legend3"));
        Chart4.Series[0].Legend = "Legend3";
        Chart4.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
        Chart4.Series[0].LegendText = "Donations";
        Chart4.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
        Chart4.BackColor = Color.PowderBlue;
        Chart4.Series[0].BorderWidth = 3;
        Chart4.Series[0].BorderColor = Color.Orange;
        Chart4.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Date";
        Chart4.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        Chart4.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackSecondaryColor = Color.White;
        Chart4.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
        Chart4.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.StripLines.Add(StripLine);
        #endregion
```

[image: Donation Chart]

Comment: `i.AddDays(7)` seems to say you're only grabbing data for one day per week...  Instead it might be good to grab all data within your date range in a single result set?

Comment: That might work. The database only contains data for one day each week, the Sunday, do you think that would mess things up?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're asking.  Your data is 1 day per week, your graph shows 1 day per week.  Are you looking for a way to average the numbers out over a week?  What do you think the graph should look like?

Comment: Okay. If you look at the shaded area (the stripline) of the chart, you'll notice that it crosses the data from 3 and a half weeks. It should instead cover a distance of one half of a week as it is right now. The axis right now is counting one week as one day in the greater week. The heart of the question is: how can I format this data so that it is counting each week as its own week instead of as a day?

Comment: So, can I get a week to represent a week instead of a day?

Comment: I'd try all StripLine intervals in Days since "Date" is your baseline.  Then increase the intervals offsets etc if needed.

Comment: Well, the reason that it isn't that simple is that I have custom controls that edit the axes based on the time frame selected. But for this instance, that will fix it. For this question, though, that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I fiddled around with it a lot more yesterday, and here was the problem: 
            string Date = i.ToShortDateString();

```
        Chart4.Series[0].Points.AddXY(Date, Donations);
```

The issue was that in order for dates to work right, they need to be added to the axis as `DateTime` variables instead of strings. As such, anything working with weeks simply counted in units of 7 strings. 
The correct code is here:

```
            Chart4.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Donations);
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx, you may try to replace these lines :

```
string Date = i.ToShortDateString();
Chart4.Series[0].Points.AddXY(Date, Donations);
```

with those :

```
  DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
  Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
  Chart4.Series[0].Points.AddXY(cal.GetWeekOfYear(i, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, 
                                      dfi.FirstDayOfWeek), Donations);
```